# bower install missing files

Tags: node.js, bower

I am running bower install insider my dir.
It creates a bower_components folder, but some .js files are missing..

```
GET /customapp/customapp.controller.js 304 7ms
GET /customapp/testmodal.controller.js 304 5ms
GET /bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/bootstrap/js/popover.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js 404 0ms
GET /bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/angular-grid/build/ng-grid.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/moment/moment.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/fullcalendar/gcal.js 404 0ms
GET /bower_components/tinymce/tinymce.min.js 404 1ms
GET /bower_components/angular-ui-tinymce/src/tinymce.js 404 1ms
```

I have tried to do delete the dir and install it again, yet it wont install correctly. These files are always missing from my bower_components dir...

I have searched for the missing files on my entire filesystem, they are not there, which is why the 404.

I am installing bower locally in my directory using this bower.json file, after having done npm install

```
{
  "name": "sccd-ng",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "app.js",
  "moduleType": [
    "node"
  ],
  "license": "xyz",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.16",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.16",
    "angular-google-chart": "~0.0.8",
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.16",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.16",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16",
    "angular-grid": "2.0.11",
    "angular-route": "1.2.16",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "json3": "~3.2.6",
    "moment": "2.5.1",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.16",
    "angular-moment": "~0.6.2",
    "jquery": "2.1.1",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.10.4",
    "angular-ui-calendar": "latest",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
    "angular-ui-tinymce": "latest",
    "vis": "latest"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "2.1.1"
  }
}
```

Running bower install && find . -name bootstrap.js

```
$ bower install && find . -name bootstrap.js
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.
2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.
git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookie
s.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.0.3
bower validate      3.0.3 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.0.3
bower cached        git://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.5.1
bower validate      2.5.1 against git://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.5.1
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.
git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid.git#2.0.11
bower validate      2.0.11 against git://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid.git#2.0.1
1
bower cached        git://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart.git#0.0.10
bower validate      0.0.10 against git://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart.g
it#~0.0.8
bower cached        git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#3.2.6
bower validate      3.2.6 against git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#~3.2.6
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-saniti
ze.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resour
ce.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.1
bower validate      2.1.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.1
bower cached        git://github.com/urish/angular-moment.git#0.6.2
bower validate      0.6.2 against git://github.com/urish/angular-moment.git#~0.6
.2
bower cached        git://github.com/components/jqueryui.git#1.10.4
bower validate      1.10.4 against git://github.com/components/jqueryui.git#~1.1
0.4
bower cached        git://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#2.1.0
bower validate      2.1.0 against git://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#~2.1.0
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenar
io.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar.git#0.8.1
bower validate      0.8.1 against git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar.git#*
bower cached        git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce.git#0.0.5
bower validate      0.0.5 against git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce.git#*
bower cached        git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#0.11.0
bower validate      0.11.0 against git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.g
it#~0.11.0
bower cached        git://github.com/almende/vis.git#3.1.0
bower validate      3.1.0 against git://github.com/almende/vis.git#*
bower cached        git://github.com/jozzhart/tinymce.git#4.0.0
bower validate      4.0.0 against git://github.com/jozzhart/tinymce.git#4.0.0
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.0-build.2974+
sha.f3a763f
bower validate      1.3.0-build.2974+sha.f3a763f against git://github.com/angula
r/bower-angular.git#~1.3
bower cached        git://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar.git#1.6.4
bower validate      1.6.4 against git://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar.git#~1.x
bower cached        git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11.1
bower validate      1.11.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#^1.8.0
bower new           version for git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.3
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.3
bower download      https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.3.0-buil
d.2982+sha.86340a5.tar.gz
bower cached        git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.10.2
bower validate      1.10.2 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~1.10.2
bower extract       angular#~1.3 archive.tar.gz
bower invalid-meta  angular is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
bower resolved      git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.0-build.2982+
sha.86340a5

Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.2.16 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-cookie
s#1.2.16, angular-mocks#1.2.16, angular-resource#1.2.16, angular-route#1.2.16, a
ngular-sanitize#1.2.16, angular-scenario#1.2.16, sccd-ng
    2) angular#~1.x which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-ui-tinym
ce#0.0.5
    3) angular#>=1 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-bootstrap
#0.11.0
    4) angular#^1.0.8 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-grid#2
.0.11
    5) angular#~1.2.x which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-ui-cal
endar#0.8.1
    6) angular#>=1.0.0 <1.3.0 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angula
r-moment#0.6.2
    7) angular#~1.3 which resolved to 1.3.0-build.2982+sha.86340a5 and is requir
ed by angular-google-chart#0.0.10

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json


[?] Answer: 1

Please note that,
    fullcalendar#1.6.4 depends on jquery#~1.10.2 which resolved to jquery#1.10.2

    angular-grid#2.0.11 depends on jquery#^1.8.0 which resolved to jquery#1.11.1

    sccd-ng depends on jquery#2.1.1 which resolved to jquery#2.1.1
    jquery-ui#1.10.4 depends on jquery#>=1.6 which resolved to jquery#2.1.1
    angular-ui-calendar#0.8.1 depends on jquery#~2.x which resolved to jquery#2.
1.1
    bootstrap#3.0.3 depends on jquery#>= 1.9.0 which resolved to jquery#2.1.1

Resort to using jquery#2.1.1 which resolved to jquery#2.1.1
Code incompatibilities may occur.

bower install       angular-ui-tinymce#0.0.5
bower install       angular-bootstrap#0.11.0
bower install       angular-ui-calendar#0.8.1
bower install       angular-moment#0.6.2
bower install       vis#3.1.0
bower install       angular-google-chart#0.0.10
bower install       json3#3.2.6
bower install       es5-shim#2.1.0
bower install       angular-grid#2.0.11
bower install       angular-route#1.2.16
bower install       angular-resource#1.2.16
bower install       angular-scenario#1.2.16
bower install       angular#1.2.16
bower install       angular-sanitize#1.2.16
bower install       jquery#2.1.1
bower install       tinymce#4.0.0
bower install       jquery-ui#1.10.4
bower install       fullcalendar#1.6.4
bower install       moment#2.5.1
bower install       angular-mocks#1.2.16
bower install       angular-cookies#1.2.16
bower install       bootstrap#3.0.3

angular-ui-tinymce#0.0.5 bower_components\angular-ui-tinymce
├── angular#1.2.16
└── tinymce#4.0.0

angular-bootstrap#0.11.0 bower_components\angular-bootstrap
└── angular#1.2.16

angular-ui-calendar#0.8.1 bower_components\angular-ui-calendar
├── angular#1.2.16
├── fullcalendar#1.6.4
├── jquery#2.1.1
└── jquery-ui#1.10.4

angular-moment#0.6.2 bower_components\angular-moment
├── angular#1.2.16
└── moment#2.5.1

vis#3.1.0 bower_components\vis

angular-google-chart#0.0.10 bower_components\angular-google-chart
└── angular#1.2.16

json3#3.2.6 bower_components\json3

es5-shim#2.1.0 bower_components\es5-shim

angular-grid#2.0.11 bower_components\angular-grid
├── angular#1.2.16
└── jquery#2.1.1

angular-route#1.2.16 bower_components\angular-route
└── angular#1.2.16

angular-resource#1.2.16 bower_components\angular-resource
└── angular#1.2.16

angular-scenario#1.2.16 bower_components\angular-scenario
└── angular#1.2.16

angular#1.2.16 bower_components\angular

angular-sanitize#1.2.16 bower_components\angular-sanitize
└── angular#1.2.16

jquery#2.1.1 bower_components\jquery

tinymce#4.0.0 bower_components\tinymce

jquery-ui#1.10.4 bower_components\jquery-ui
└── jquery#2.1.1

fullcalendar#1.6.4 bower_components\fullcalendar
└── jquery#2.1.1

moment#2.5.1 bower_components\moment

angular-mocks#1.2.16 bower_components\angular-mocks
└── angular#1.2.16

angular-cookies#1.2.16 bower_components\angular-cookies
└── angular#1.2.16

bootstrap#3.0.3 bower_components\bootstrap
└── jquery#2.1.1
```

Comment: There really isn't anywhere near enough information for us to debug this. 
You're showing 404 errors, which indicates that an HTTP server can't find the assets... are you saying that the *files* are not in your filesystem?

Comment: If you are on a Linux system, what does `find . -name bootstrap.js` show, when run from the same location as your HTTP server?

Comment: Did you run `bower install`?

Comment: yep, ran bower install, and it was missing these files. so then deleted the bower_components, tried again, still no luck..

Comment: I ran it locally and the file is definitely there.
Can you run the following:
`bower install && find . -name bootstrap.js` and post the full response, please?

Answer (score 10):

Doing bower cache clean, then renaming the bower_components and doing bower install again fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### The cause (?):

I can reliably reproduce this problem under the following circumstances:

1. Running my mean-stack app via Grunt task runner: `node --debug server.js`
2. Switching branches in git from my `development` branch to `release`

   - My `development` branch pulls all bower packages straight from `bower install`
   - My `release` branch has minified instances checked in to ease deployment
3. At this point, my bower directory, `public/lib/` is in a bad state and the problem occurs.

#### My Solution:

1. Stop any node processes before changing branches
2. there is no 2

As stated above, if you get into this situation, nuke your bower library. That does the trick for me, but you can clean your cache as well if its still broken.